# Angular 8 on google cloud, application_readable not working

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed an app to GCP with the following yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: app/index.html
  upload: app/index.html
  application_readable: true
- url: /
  static_dir: app 
  application_readable: true
```

I have used the `application_readable` item to render the original mime type, but you can see in the image bellow that it is rendered as plain text.

[image]

I have made sue that correct app.yaml is deployed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The current solution now it to add `type="text/javascript"` in your `<script></script>`

For example

```
<script src="runtime-es2015.js"  type="module" ></script>
<script src="polyfills-es2015.js"  type="module" ></script>
```

becomes

```
<script src="runtime-es2015.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="polyfills-es2015.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

This is just a hack. Hopefully, someone can fix this properly